# Unable to run graalvm gu command on mac

Tags: macos, graalvm

I have installed graalvm on mac, and I see gu utility in /bin folder of the installation directory. When I try to run a gu command inside /bin folder, like

```
gu install native-image
```

I get message:

```
zsh: command not found: gu
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Same problem here. I downloaded https://download.oracle.com/graalvm/21/latest/graalvm-jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz and the gu tool (GraalVM updater) is nowhere under $GRAALVM/bin

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the following in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

```sh
 export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<graalvm>/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH
```

You may missed it during the installation procedure. For complete guide, please check [official installation instruction](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/docs/getting-started/macos/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the path. Try:

`./gu install native-image`

Answer (score 0):

The GraalVM Updater was removed on JDK 21.

> Blockquote
> We plan to remove the GraalVM Updater and provide GraalVM language plugins and other GraalVM extensions in new ways.

https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/6855